# How to add Edittext and Spinner when I clicked on Add button in java code?

Tags: java, android

```
package com.nyurals.school;



import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SettingsActitivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings );

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.show();
        actionBar.setTitle("SETTINGS");

        int titleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(titleId);
    //  textView.setText("ANNOUNCEMENTS");
        textView.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.BLUE);

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        init();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void init() {

        //textParentName = (TextView) findViewById(R.)
        String[] items = { "Nursery", "KG-I", "KG-II", "I", "II",
                "III", "IV", "V" };
        Spinner spinnerForClass = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerClass);
        //      spinnerForClass.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerClass = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);

        spinnerForClass.setAdapter(spinnerClass);
    }

    public void addChildren(View view) {


        Toast.makeText(SettingsActitivity.this, "Clicked on Add", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_settings, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.item_save:
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActitivity.this, "Details saved.. Thank You!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;

        default:
            return false;

        }

    }



}
```

In above code in add Children method, What should I write to add child again???? i.e. How to add Edit Text and Spinner like it is already present there which came from XML..
please suggest any solution...

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/7090771/1393623

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have Spinner and EditText in xml already and want to add again by probgrammatically then first remove all views from your parent layout..

like:

```
  parentlayout.removeAllViews();
```

and after that create object for **Spinner** and **EditText** and add to parent layout

```
  EditText edt= new EditText(this);
  Spinner sp= new Spinner(this);
  parentlayout.addView(edt);
  parentlayout.addView(sp);
```

Comment: yes.. It is okk but I want previous views also and after clickin on addchildren, in View (Activity), below edittext and spinner row , i want same thing to appear, If user have two or more children, so on the same activity, he can enter there informations... so, it needs to adjust layout height... please do reply as i need this..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
EditText myEdtTxt = new EditText(this);
myLayout.addView(myEdtTxt);

Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
myLayout.addView(spinner);
```