# Set and Get Id in Edittext in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am using Multiple Edittext in same view. So i am conflicting which editext view click. so Setting here first id and then get id. but  unable to get id, clickable edittext's.

**My Code:** http://pastebin.com/CiBkz1Yd

```
List<EditText> edittext_list = new ArrayList<EditText>();
 Private EditText txtBox ;

for(int j=0, j=<3; j++){
txtBox = new EditText(context);
edittext_list.add(txtBox);
    txtBox.setId(j);
}

    txtBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


    public void afterTextChanged( Editable s) {

    How to get here that clicked edittext id:
    }
    });
```

**EDIT:**
same things works on button:

```
btn_guide= new Button(context);
    btn_guide.setId(j);

    btn_guide.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     if i do this-->>v.getId();    then getting but how to above???
}
});
```

if i use focuschangelistener then works:

```
txtBox.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
                    {
                        private int id_focus;


                        @Override
                        public void onFocusChange(View vv, boolean hasFocus) 
                        {
                            if (hasFocus == false)
                            {
                                System.out.println("FALSE "+vv.getId());
                            }else {
                                id_focus=vv.getId();

                                System.out.println("TRUE ID "+vv.getId());
                                for (int k = 0; k < edit_text_value_list.size(); k++){
                                    if (edit_text_value_list.get(k).getId() == id_focus) {
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "you have clicked=="+elemName.get(k).toString()+ edit_text_value_list.get(k).getText().toString(), 5000).show();
                                    }
                                }
```

Comment: try int `id=txtBox.getId();`

Comment: every edittext clicked, i got 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you creating custom class,May help for you, use this:

```
List<EditText> edittext_list = new ArrayList<EditText>();
 Private EditText txtBox ;

for(int j=0, j=<3; j++){
txtBox = new EditText(context);
edittext_list.add(txtBox);
    txtBox.setId(j);
getEditTextValue(txtBox);
}
```

DO, whatever you want in addTextChangedListenerlistener:

```
 private void getEditTextValue(final EditText txtBox3) {
    txtBox3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        if (s.length() == 0)
                         {
                             return;
                         }

    System.out.println("txtBox3 "+ txtBox3.getId());
            for (int k = 0; k < edittext_list .size(); k++){
                if (edittext_list .get(k).getId() == txtBox3.getId()) {
//Do, whatevery your clicked editext after input.
      }
     }
    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                });    

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for store edittext value :-

**set id on edittext**

```
EditText ed;
List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {   

    ed = new EditText(Activity2.this);
    allEds.add(ed);
    ed.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blackOpacity);
    ed.setId(id);   
    ed.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linear.addView(ed);
}
```

**get value from edittext**

```
String[] strings = new String[](allEds.size());

for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
    string[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
}
```

for more info see below link:-

[Add edittext dynamically and retrieve values in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077275/add-edittext-dynamically-and-retrieve-values-in-android)

Comment: So, i saw this tutorials also, but how to use in above my problem. any idea, addTextChangedListener then getting id.

Answer (score 0):

in your code your edittext will be override with a single id so it'll happen and you got the same id every time.

----------------Your code --------------------

```
for(int j=0, j=<3; j++){
EditText txtBox = new EditText(context);
    txtBox.setId(j);
}
```

---------- change the code---------------

This will happen because every time you need to new object for your component here you just declared it globally.

```
private EditText;

    for(int j=0, j=<3; j++){
     txtBox = new EditText(context);
        txtBox.setId(j);
    }
```

Comment: Actually i done outside, but my concern how to get id in afterTextChanged. look, my code. http://pastebin.com/CiBkz1Yd

Answer (score 0):

Here I can see you need 4 edittext to add in your layout. SO make an array of edittext of size 4. like below :

```
Private EditText txtBox[] = new EditText[4] ;
```

Now you need to have ids for each edittext, so for that you'll have to create another array of integer which will contain ids and yes it will be again of 4 size.

```
private int idsForEditText[] = new int[4];
```

Now you'll put ids in the ids array :

```
    for(int j = 0; j<txtBox.length; i++){
       txtBox[j].setId(j);
       idsForEditText[j] = j;
}
```

Now you can apply addTextChangeListener for each edittext like below :

```
EditText editFirst = (EditText)findViewById(idsForEditText[0]);
EditText editSecond = (EditText)findViewById(idsForEditText[1]);
EditText editThird = (EditText)findViewById(idsForEditText[2]);
EditText editFourth = (EditText)findViewById(idsForEditText[3]);
```

`editFirst.addTextChangedListener ()` and so on..

Hope this will help you :

Answer (score 0):

Its so simple.

declare integer variable like Below code :

```
 numberofpasses[totalitems].addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    int total;
    String value;
    int id=numberofpasses[totalitems].getId();
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       value=arg0.toString();
       if(!value.equals(""))
       {
           total=Integer.valueOf(prc)*Integer.valueOf(value);
           txttotal[id].setText(String.valueOf(total));
       }
       }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

`EditText txtBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1)//which is used in your xml`

Comment: I have creating edittext from programmatically. you did not see above.